# Getting as set off by it

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I'm reading an article about anxiety. The author says that when people feel anxious, they try to make themselves feel better by applying all kinds of coping techniques (e.g. deep breathing). Then it goes on to say:

> Those tools have value, but if you get better at simply tolerating your physical anxiety, and not getting as set off by it, then you won't need to use them as much.

I know what "to set off" means, but isn't it used here as an adjective? Couldn't you say that anxiety makes you "set-off"? Or it is instead used as a normal verb?

Thank you

Comment: Have you ever "set off" a firecracker?

Comment: ***As*** *set off* is strange—especially without more context. Normally, it would be used as a comparison. Not getting as set off by your physical anxiety *as* ***what***? I suspect there is some essential context missing. Either that or it's poorly phrased.

Comment: The most likely explanation here, if there is no comparison, is that the author should have used *not getting **so** set off by it*.

Comment: And it is still a verb: *My anxiety* ***set me off***.

Comment: The comparison, @JasonBassford, is with tolerating versus getting set off by.

Comment: @Xanne That doesn't make sense to me. That's not a comparison. If that's the interpretation, then it should be **so**, not **as**. With **as**, it should read something like *not getting **as** set off by it as you did before …*

Comment: @JasonBassford I agree “not so” is better. But the author clearly intends a comparison, however poorly stated.

Comment: set off here means triggered. To set off anxiety, to trigger it. get=become. However, the grammar is still awkward. If you are not becoming triggered by it.

Comment: Compare 'het up' (from 'heated up'), which all the dictionaries say is a (two word) adjective. But 'He was het up by the remark' is not available. ' ... set off by ...' looks like a passive multi-word verb usage. If one wants to split hairs by insisting on one classification or the other here, one will excuse me.

Answer (score -1):

> Those tools have value, but if you get better at simply tolerating
>   your physical anxiety, and not getting as set off by it, then you
>   won't need to use them as much.

If you don't let your physical anxiety "set you off" then you don't need to use the "tools" as much.

Here, being "set off" is being made angry.  That is, being metaphorically ignited, like a firecracker -- "My mother-in-law always sets me off!!"

But note that "set off" can be used in an adjectival sense:  "I felt really set off after I read that."

Comment: What makes it seem like an adjective is the use of the comparative "as" before it.

Comment: @Barmar - Yep, I would say it's being used as an adjective, since it's implying a "degree" of "set-offedness".

Comment: Have you a supporting reference (not just the odd example) for the adjectival usage?